# How can I create this sliding JS motion?

Tags: javascript, motion

I'm having trouble finding how to create this motion on http://makr.com/ - when you click on a product, the page slides down and more product information appears. The scrollbar also scrolls to where the product/information fits on the whole page. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both using jQuery.

- For the **opening** the product on the way they do: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- For the **scrolling** you can check this page: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

The general idea is trigger the scroll method once you click in a product (scrolling to the place you want) and then open the product details by using animate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `ul.products li.product` selector selects every product in the list.
Let's say `div.product-detail` selector selects the correspondent product detail container

```
$(".ul.products li.product").click(function() {

    $('div.product-detail').slideDown(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
    });
});
```

You may want to select a specific product detail div (the one related with the clicked product) but this code accomplish the purpose.

offset property gives you the top/left coordinates of the product detail div.

Answer (score -1):

use scrollTo() method.

[developer.mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo).

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. see [W3Fools - A W3Schools Intervention](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @ZebRawnsley i hate them as well they are decent for a reference though usually

Comment: w3schools is evil and harmful. Use Mozilla Developer Network instead. [Here is reference for `window.scroll` and similar methods on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo). -1 for referring w3schools.

Comment: @Tadeck i added a mozilla developer reference please check the edit, he IS evil and harmful, but has good `try it yourself` examples.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: For "try it yourself" use eg. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). MDN lacks similar approach, but since you get it from sites like jsfiddle, w3schools has not added value (not mentioning the harm it has done over the years, fooling people to believe it has something to do with standards, so they were using it as reference, propagating bad habits at the same time). I promise that if you will create your example with some tool like jsfiddle, add reference to something like MDN and erase any reference to w3schools, I will turn my downvote to upvote.

Comment: @Tadeck no problem i will galdly delete it (btw i started learning from w3schools and i am still suffering as a result) check my edit